# My jpegs not good enough for jssor slider?

Tags: jpeg, osx-mavericks, jssor

I've been playing with jssor sliders, specifically with different-size-photo-slider. It works when I run the demo version, but when I add my own jpegs, generated by Aperture on OS X from RAW format, those images never finish loading. The loading animated icon just stays forever. The files and pixel sizes are not different from the jssor images. It looks like my jpegs fail to be resized. I tried both Safari and Firefox. Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: This question has a rather tenuous connection to programming, but I think you are looking for a "Save for web"-type feature, like [Aperture and "Save for Web"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5852919).

Comment: Please check if you can access the image url directly by your browser.

Comment: According to server technology, sometimes you need to specify case sensitive url.

Comment: When I use a different slider (also jssor) and create jpegs of the right size it all works. It seems like my jpegs cannot be resized by jssor scripts. I tested it by putting one additional jpeg to img folder. The slider works until it encounters my jpeg when it shows load icon forever.

Comment: I switched to Adobe 1998 colormap and it works!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I export from Aperture with the default colormap, which is sRGB IEC611966-2.1, javascript has problems resizing the picture. Using, or maybe just changing to, Adobe 1998 or Generic RGB makes things work fine. BTW. the source is Nikon raw file with sRGB color map.